# Formatando textbox

Tags: vb.net

Olá, eu estou com um problema de formatação na caixa de texto que é o seguinte
Eu estou usando o seguinte codigo para formatar a caixa de texto de acordo com o numero de telefone

```
If Len(numtel) = 11 Then CaixaTxt.Text = Format(numtel, "(##) ##### ####")
    If Len(numtel) = 10 Then CaixaTxt.Text = Format(numtel, "(##) #### ####")
    If Len(numtel) = 9 Then CaixaTxt.Text = Format(numtel, "( ) ##### ####")
    If Len(numtel) = 8 Then CaixaTxt.Text = Format(numtel, "( ) #### ####")
```

porém a caixa de texto ao inves de ser formatada com o numero e com o formato, esta recebendo o texto: Ex: len = 8 a caixa fica "( ) #### ####" com o espaço as aspas e a # ao invés de números... 
Alguém sabe o que eu estou fazer errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema será, mais provavelmente, que a variável `numtel` seja do tipo `String`, o que impede que a formatação seja aplicada.

A solução passa por converter para inteiro e então fazer a conversão, mais ou menos desta forma:

```
If IsNumeric(numtel) Then
    Dim intNumtel As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(numtel)
    Dim strNumtel As String

    Select Case Len(numtel)
        Case 11 : strNumtel = Format(intNumtel, "(##) ##### ####")
        Case 10 : strNumtel = Format(intNumtel, "(##) #### ####")
        Case 9 : strNumtel = Format(intNumtel, "( ) ##### ####")
        Case 8 : strNumtel = Format(intNumtel, "( ) #### ####")
    End Select

    CaixaTxt.Text = strNumtel
End If
```

Comment: Não percebi o voto negativo... ao dar voto negativo deveriam explicar o porquê, de forma a quem colocou a solução perceber o que estará de errado e alterar o que for necessário para ajudar o utilizador a encontrar uma que seja válida!

Comment: Muito obrigada! Resolveu meu problema :D
Quanto ao voto negativo, eu também não entendi... A solução funcionou perfeitamente
Agradeço seu tempo!

Comment: De nada! Aproveite e dê um UP na resposta :)

Comment: Eu dei, mas como não tenho mais de 15 pts de reputação, so conta no sistema e não marca o voto... não entendi o porque disso, mas tudo bem! de toda forma foi de muita ajuda